# Sorting numbers digit wise

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, data-structures, stl-algorithm

I have N numbers and I want to sort each number by digit. ( In my original problem I want to make the largest number by these (greedy approach)) For ex - If we have 5 numbers 9 1000 845 8000 56 In first step I will pick 9 as 9 is the highest of all 1st digit of numbers

In second step ( as 9 is already picked), next highest first digit is 8, but when 2 or more numbers have same digit I will compare their next digit so I will pick 845.

In this if I sort I will get the following result 9 845 8000 56 1000.

My question is how can implement this in c++ ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Convert the numbers to strings, then sort the strings?

Comment: Is it correct that in your sorting, `0` is *after* `4`? Because that calls for a complete custom compare, as in numeric as well as lexicographic order, `0 < 4`...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected result by passing a custom compare function to the `sort` function.

The compare function may be like this:

```cpp
bool compare(int a, int b) {
    ostringstream x, y;
    x << a; y << b;
    return x.str() > y.str();
}


...
    sort(array, array+n, compare);
...
```

In this compare function, we are converting the `integer` data to `string` data and simply comparing the string values to get the expected sorted array.

Comment: One liner: `std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array), [](int lhs, int rhs){ return std::to_string(lhs) > std::to_string(rhs); });`